# Create middleware for admin user with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, middleware

I build an simple app and I have Users, but some users need to have admin privilegies, so I try to create this:

1. First at migration file I add boolean type - admin:

   public function up()

   ```
    {
           Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
               $table->increments('id');
               $table->boolean('admin');
               $table->string('username');
               $table->string('email')->unique();
               $table->string('password', 60);
               $table->rememberToken();
               $table->timestamps();
           });
       }
   ```

after that I create new middleware:

```
class RedirectIfNotAManager
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $request->user()->IsATeamManager()){

            return redirect('articles');

        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

offcource Now I need to create function IsATeamManager() at User model file:

```
public function IsATeamManager(){
        if ($this->is('admin') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

at Kernel.php I add manager:

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'manager' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAManager::class,

    ];
```

At route I add:

```
Route::get('foo', ['middleware'=>'manager', function(){

    return 'This Page is Only for Managers';

}]);
```

Manually at phpMyAdmin I change the user admin column for some users at '1'... I log as that user,

But when I try to go at: localhost:8888/foo I get this error:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2071: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::is()

What I also try is to chech is authenticated user admin when i make request so I write:

```
public function store(Requests\ArticleRequest $request)
    {
        $article = new Article($request->all());

        Auth::user()->is('admin')->articles()->save($article);

        return redirect('articles');
    }
```

but that doesn work and I dont know why... so my request is if authenticated users have admin column true then save article...

What you suggest? How to implement user admin at my app?

Comment: Looks like your user model doesn't have a `is` function.

Comment: but 'is' is buildIn function ?

Comment: No, `is` is not a built-in function. http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html

Comment: ok , I add use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 to user model but again is the same

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Take a look at [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) and [Roles](https://github.com/romanbican/roles).

Comment: Why would you think adding `Request` would do anything? Its `is` function doesn't have anything to do with roles. You need to write your *own* roles system, with its own `is` function, or install a package that does.

Comment: Why this simply dont work: Auth::user()->where('admin', 1)->articles()->save($article); - I think its the best and simlest way to chech admin auth ...

Comment: That'll work **if** you have a column called `admin` on the `users` table and set the administrators to `1` in it. If you don't have that column, it's not going to work. You really should start understanding the basics of Laravel and PHP before you code.

Comment: but yes, I have admin column on user tabel ...

Comment: i find solution by this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253111/simplest-solution-for-check-is-user-admin-or-not-with-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should replace this:

```
Auth::user()->is('admin')->articles()->save($article);
```

with this:

```
Auth::user()->where('admin', 1)->articles()->save($article);
```

Comment: hm, NO, I try this: public function index() {

        $articles = Auth::user()->where('admin', 1)->articles()->latest()->get();
        return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));

    } but I get this error: BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2071:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::articles() ... I use laravel 5.1 version